# Azure DocumentDB 4 bytes UTF8 encoding

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a problem with sign  (https://mothereff.in/utf-8#%F0%A5%94%8E)

It is apparently stored as "\ud855\udd0e"

Here is part of JSON from Azure query explorer: "FirstName": "X \ud855\udd0e X 惠 霞 垄" (other chinese characters work - they are not 4-bytes)

My app (Java based) uses Spring boot mongodb to connect.
When I use local mongodb installation (with default config), it works correctly...

Data flow is following:
External data source -> Java App 1 -> Azure -> Java App 2 -> Mysql

Is it somehow configurable? Is it a bug in Azure?

Comment: you're seeing this because the codepage is not the correct one to be reading these characters. you need to read it in as UTF-8 codepage 65001.

Comment: Thanks for hint, but could you elaborate? If you refer to the web browser encoding, than it is not that - I also import these data from Azure into mysql, and in mysql GUI (HeidiSQL - standalone app) I see exactly the same behaviour. If you mean changing the mongodb API connection encoding, could you write how?

Comment: that's why I wrote this as a comment and not as an answer. I'm not sure how you'd do it in the setup you have. I've recently had a similar issue using SSIS into MS SQL. The issue will most likely reside in your interface from the source UTF-8 data to the Azure DB. you need to load it in with the correct encryption.

Comment: if the AzureDB is your source, try reading it with the correct encryption.

Comment: I tried creating a document in Azure DocumentDB with id:  "X  X 惠 霞 垄" using the C# SDK and I was able to view it correctly in the Query Explorer in Azure Document portal. My guess is that this is not getting serialized/deserialized correctly in your app. What SDK are you using to create this document in DocumentDB? May be that has an issue(since you are seeing the same behavior in other tool).

Comment: @Intern87, thanks for writing. I work in Java, I use Spring boot framework. I have added the data flow info. The whole flow works well when I use local mongodb installation. Does not with Azure. It suggest that the encoding problem happens on connection with Azure, but I cannot find any info how could i change the connection encoding....

Comment: @RajeshNagpal, thanks for testing, please see my comment above